# sqlcmd not working during setup (innosetup)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

nice to meet you, i always lurk here as soon as i get some problem; but now it seems i'm having some strange issue i didn't find any trace here.

Using InnoSetup i created a setup that runs, as long as others, 2 Batches;

The first one installs SQL EXPRESS 2008 With tools (%n are parameters passed with innosetup):

```
C:\omi\setup\sql\setup.exe /QS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL,Tools /INSTANCENAME=%1 /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="omicron" /TCPENABLED=1
PAUSE
```

And it seems to end successfully.

The issue comes with the second batch:

```
sqlcmd -d master -S .\%1 -q "CREATE DATABASE arca ON ( FILENAME = N'C:\omi\db\arca_Data.MDF' ), ( FILENAME = N'C:\omi\db\arca_Log.LDF') FOR ATTACH"
PAUSE
```

since the prompt tells that sqlcmd is not recognised as internal or external command, nor executable or batch.

what dazzles me is the fact that if i write the same command manually, is work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems doesn't detect it in the system's PATH 
within one installation session and is executed under a user which doesn't see the PATH environment which has been changed. 
First it is executed under /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" then it seems that it uses a different user. It looks like it sets the PATH variable only for the Network Service user.